# Android UI automator: open the app twice, test interaction

Tags: android, testing, android-uiautomator

I want to write test cases using UI Automator that involve logging in 2 users, in 2 different emulators or devices, and test interactions between them.

For example, a chat application could use this to verify that messages are sent and received, added contacts get notifications, etc.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: By "2 different apps", do you really mean two separate apps (separate installs, separate `applicationId` values, etc.)? If so, then this should be possible, assuming that your interactions with the apps are within the limits of what Ui Automator supports (e.g., no fancy touch events) and assuming that you can get your test results through means that Ui Automator supports (e.g., getting text from `TextView`).

Comment: I meant two different instances of the same application, but I could engineer two different builds with different application IDs. How would I run both test suites, and be able to "synchronize" them? For example, if a test fails, the other shouldn't keep going. Or, how would I make it work in CI serviceS?

Comment: "I meant two different instances of the same application" -- this is not possible in Android. "How would I run both test suites" -- you would only have one test suite, using Ui Automator to automate both apps.

Comment: Both things are strictly true. However, just to name one potential alternative, running two different subsets of the test suite on two different devices or emulators could be made to work, with some scripting and adapting. It wouldn't surprise me if someone had already done something similar.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I assumed you were aiming for a single emulator or test device.